# Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, 23.04 Laptop freezes after suspend

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, suspend, 23.04

I really love Ubuntu and I need to use this somehow.

I tried several times reinstalling ubuntu in my laptop. Specs,

```
Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS
core i3 11 gen - Lenovo v15 g2 ITL
NVME + 1 TB HDD    8 GB Ram
```

After sometimes I keep my laptop on it automatically suspend. After suspend when the screen turn on It's freezes can't even shutdown or reboot. After somehow if I manage to turn on my laptop again a disk check is running.

I really love Ubuntu and I want to use it somehow without any error. Please help me.
Note: I have done making suspend mode turn off. But it's not a solution since a suspension/sleep is necessary to maintain a good health for the hardware components. Thanks.

Comment: You've provided no clear Ubuntu product/release details; mentioning three different releases without clear details as to which product (Server? Desktop? etc)  If you're talking about desktop systems, did you explore using an *alternate* kernel stack?   (ie. use another set of kernel modules aka *drivers*) and the issue was likely just a stuck GUI thus commands for shutdown/explore may still have been possible, but your *unclear* details make it hard to suggest.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for responding I have updated my question

Comment: How do the other releases you've tagged relate?  The question still isn't clear as highlights its about 3 different releases form 2020, 2022 & 2023 and then clearly mentions one.  22.04 is a LTS release thus has kernel stack options (*as does 20.04 you also tagged*) but you didn't mention if you tried using SysRq commands to bypass any *stuck GUI* or what you tried  (on restart the disk check implies you're not using a safe shutdown command, but gave no specific details)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem only with Ubuntu 23.04, both on my laptop and PC. Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Tuxedo OS2, and any other Ubuntu-based Linux that is using 23.04. Not only from Suspend but even when turning on the PC from Hibernation. It only shows Wallpaper before the login screen, and nothing else works. I have no other choice but to force shut down my computer or my laptop.